# How to limit SSL fragment size with lighttpd webserver?

Tags: ssl, openssl, lighttpd

I am using the lighttpd webserver and enabled ssl with openssl.
Now i need to limit fragment size as mentioned in [RFC 6066 (Chapter 4)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-4).

Is there any option in the lighttpd.conf file? Or any other possibility to limit the fragment size?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crosspost in Lighttpd Forums: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/6344

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution for that so far.
Answer on redmine.lighttpd.net:

> there is none and i am not aware of any webserver or proxy (like haproxy) implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to limit fragment size, you might look at the new lighttpd 1.4.45 directive `ssl.read-ahead = "disable"` for use on low-memory systems.